# Why is typescript setting my value to a 'undefined' string instead of an undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a select dropdown where I set the first value to a undefined.

But the problem is if I select a dropdown value and then go and select the first value ('All') then my bound variable ends up becoming a string 'undefined' and it actually changes it from a number to a string.

```
memberParams.membership // is a :number and I don't want it to be converted to a string
```

and memberTypes is a name/value pair

```
export interface IMemberType {
   value: number;
   name: string;
}
```

Why is this and how can I prevent it?

```js
this.memberTypes = [{value: undefined, name: 'All'}, ...response.memberships];
```

```html
<select class="form-control custom-select w-100" name="memberType" [(ngModel)]="memberParams.membership">
  <option *ngFor="let memberType of memberTypes" [value]="memberType.value">
    {{memberType.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you just omit the `value` altogether and use an `*ngIf member.value else all`?

Comment: no because memberTypes is an interface with a name/value pair

Comment: Why not make the value optional then? `undefined` is not a number so the object is already lying about its type.

Comment: what do you mean optional?

Comment: @user1186050 You can change it to `value?: number;`

Answer (score 0):

The HTML value property is always either a number or a string. So, there is no way to fix it in the Angular template. However, inside your component you can have a setter and getter which can change the value correctly.

Inside your component:

```
get membership() {
  return this.memberParams.membership;
}

set membership(value: string | number) { 
  this.memberParams.membership = val === "undefined"? undefined : value;
}
```

You only need to make one small change in your template, which is to change the `[(ngModel)]` binding from `memberParams.membership` to just `membership`.

Comment: Hi Sid. While I think this will work, I'm not going to mark it as a the accepted answer as I think I'm looking for something else. FYI - This value is being passed to my controller as part of a search query, and when I set this value it needs to be a number or undefined/null. My check for a number is just "if (value)" -> then set the http param. I can easily fix it by adding another check "if (!'undefined'). Your answer works but requires a little more work than just having that additional check.